# Циклы For, Сумма и произведение чисел.

Tags: pascal

1. По данному натуральному числу N найдите сумму чисел 1+1/1!+1/2!+1/3!+...+1/N!. Количество действий должно быть пропорционально N.
2. что то я не очень понимаю как решить данную задачку, решить нужно только с помощью цикла for.
3. Геометрическая прогрессия. По данному действительному числу a и натуральному n вычислите сумму 1+a+a2+...+an, не используя формулу суммы геометрической прогрессии. Время работы программы должно быть пропорционально n.
4. Ну тут более менее понятно, вот что пока получилось написать:

1

```
****
program Main;
var
sum, ai, a, j, n: longint;
begin
readln(a,n);
ai := 1;
for j := 1 to n do  ai := a * ai; sum := sum + ai; writeln(sum);
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a, sum:real
begin
    a:=1;
    sum:=a;
    for i := 1 to n do   
    begin
       a := a/i;
       sum := sum + a;
    end; 
    writeln(sum); 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  Sum, Fakt: Real;
  i, n: Byte;
begin
  Write(' n = ');
  ReadLn(n);
  Sum := 1; //  при n = 0, sum = 1, так как
  Fakt := 1; // 0! = 1
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    Fakt := Fakt * i;  // n! = (n-1)*n, и не надо нахрен никакой рекурсии для вычисления факториала числа!!!
    Sum := Sum + 1/Fakt;
  end;
  WriteLn('Sum = ', Sum:1:9);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: пока писал @renegator опередил :)

Answer (score -1):

```
   for j := 1 to n do  
    begin
      ai := a * j;// proizv 
      sum := sum + ai; // summ
      writeln(sum);
    end;
```

вроде как-то так

Answer (score -2):

Вот первая задача.

```
Var
  Sum: Real;
  i, n: Byte;

Function Fakt(n: Byte): LongInt;
Var
  f: LongInt;
  i: Byte;
Begin
  f:=1;

  If (N<2) Then
    Begin
      Fakt:=1;
      Exit;
    End;

  For i:=2 To N Do
    f:=f*i;
  Fakt:=f;
End;

begin
  Write(' n = ');
  ReadLn(n);

  Sum:=1;
  For i:=1 To N Do
    Sum:=Sum+1/Fakt(i);

  WriteLn('Sum = ', Sum:1:9);
  ReadLn;
end
```

.